# Get distance between two different latitude and longitude in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, haversine

I have used  `locationA.distanceTo(locationB);`
and also have copy pasted a method written for **haversine formula.**

> The actual distance between the two geopoints is 25m but i get a
>   result of  6894.52192658389 using the above methods.

Followed this:[Creating a method using Haversine Formula, Android V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787235/creating-a-method-using-haversine-formula-android-v2)
and this [Find distance between two points on map using Google Map API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394366/find-distance-between-two-points-on-map-using-google-map-api-v2)

Checked distance using this free tool http://www.onlineconversion.com/map_greatcircle_distance.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below :

```
public static float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371000; //meters
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
               Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);

    return dist;
    }
```

It will gives you the result in meters, you can convert to any required unit.

Comment: Hi, This method uses Haversine formula and returns
 returns the value 6894.52192658389

Comment: @NishonTandukar can you give me the co-ordinates and the expected result ?

Comment: turns out i had been clumsy and had forgot to se tLatitute on destination location