# Google maps API for nearby police station

Tags: android

How to get near by police station using maps in our app ?Is there any API for this ?
I am new to android please help.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should provide your own coordinates (latitude, longitude) of all police station, in your city at least. And place it as a marker on Google Maps in your phone. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker for info about placing marker on maps.

If you wants to see only a nearby police station. You can count your current distance with all police station coordinates and show only some marker that close to your current position. For example, you can some method that already provided by Location class to calculate distance between two Geo Points. See this reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787235/creating-a-method-using-haversine-formula-android-v2)